# How can i make these tabs Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

When I open the site on a mobile then last tab merge with others tabs, and last tab will have a linebreak.
But I am not expert in media Query in CSS3. How do I apply this code, if there is some other way then mine give your best solution regarding my issue. 
I don't want to use Bootstrap because my website consists of custom designing in html and css.

```js
  document.getElementById('content_4').style.display = 'none';
  function tabSwitch(new_tab, new_content) {
     
    document.getElementById('content_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content_3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('content_4').style.display = 'none';        
    document.getElementById(new_content).style.display = 'block';   
     
 
    document.getElementById('tab_1').className = '';
    document.getElementById('tab_2').className = '';
    document.getElementById('tab_3').className = ''; 
    document.getElementById('tab_4').className = '';        
    document.getElementById(new_tab).className = 'activy';      
 
}
function tabSwitch_2(activy, number, tab_prefix, content_prefix) {
     
    for (var i=1; i < number+1; i++) {
      document.getElementById(content_prefix+i).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(tab_prefix+i).className = '';
    }
    document.getElementById(content_prefix+activy).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(tab_prefix+activy).className = 'activy';    
     
}
```

```css
        #tabbed_box {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width:300px;
}
.tabbed_box h4 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:23px;
    color:#ffffff;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.tabbed_box h4 small {
    color:#e3e9ec;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    left:6px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
}

ul.tabs {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:black;
    padding:8px 14px 8px 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border:1px solid #F4FBFF;
    border-radius: 2px; 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 1px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 1px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background-color:#3498DB;
    color:#fff;
    border-color:#3498DB;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
ul.tabs li a.activy {
    background-color:#3498DB;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #3498DB; 
    

}
.content {
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px;

 
}

#content_2, #content_3 { display:none; }
ul.tabs {
    margin:0px; padding:0px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
.content ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.content ul li {
    list-style:none;
    
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    font-size:13px;
}
.content ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#3e4346;
}
.content ul li a small {
    color:#8b959c;
    font-size:9px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    left:4px;
    top:0px;
}
.content ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    background-image:url(images/tab_off.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;  
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

```html
    
  
 
<div id="tabbed_box_1" class="tabbed_box">
    
    <div class="tabbed_area">
     <br>
        
            <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');" id="tab_1" class="activy">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_2', 'content_2');" id="tab_2">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_3', 'content_3');" id="tab_3">Facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_4', 'content_4');" id="tab_4">Social Media</a></li>
</ul>
        
         
        <div id="content_1" class="content">
           <img src="http://www.reputationbeast.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Image-0011.png"/ style="float:left; width:320px; height:250px; ">
          <p style="float:left;  text-align:center; font-style:italic; padding-top:80px; padding-left:30px; font-size:20px;"><b>"Nothing delivers<br/> your message <br/> like a text message."</b></p>
        </div>
        <div id="content_2" class="content greybg">
            <img src="http://www.reputationbeast.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Image-002.png"/ style="float:left; margin-right:30px; width:250px; height:180px; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:40px;">
          <p style="float:left; text-align:center; font-style:italic;">
          <p style="margin-left:20px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;color:#2072bf; margin-top:30px;"><i>How effective is email?</i></p>
           <p style="font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">Spam filters and an overwhelmed inbox means only 1 out of 5 emails are opened. And, of those only 1 out of 7 generates a response.   </p>
           </p>
        </div>
        <div id="content_3" class="content">
           <img src="http://www.reputationbeast.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Image-003.png"/ style="float:left;  margin-right:30px; width:260px; height:220px; margin-bottom:30px;">
          <p style="float:left;  text-align:center; font-style:italic; padding-left:5px;">
          <p style="margin-left:20px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;color:#2072bf; margin-top:30px;" ><i>How about Facebook?</i></p>
           <p style="margin-left:20px;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">Facebook lost its immediacy years ago. Organic reach has dropped to less than 2% which means you have to pay-to-play to reach more fans and at Facebook's pace.</p>
           </p>
        </div>
        <div id="content_4" class="content">
           <img src="http://www.reputationbeast.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Image-004.png"/ style="float:left; margin-right:70px;width:220px; height:180px; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:40px;">
          <p style="float:left;  text-align:center; font-style:italic; padding-left:8px;">
          <p style="margin-left:20px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;color:#2072bf; margin-top:30px;" ><i>...and other Social Media?</i></p>
           <p style="margin-left:20px;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">Twitter, Google+, Instagram, Pinterest, and every other Social Media site controls access to your fans, most offer a pay option. The best option - your own Text lists.</p>
           </p>
        </div>
     
    </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: How this question is anyhow related to php

Comment: oh really sorry i tag by mistake really sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add   `display: inline-block;` for `ul.tabs li a` this will help

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/1b2m3rsq/